# Server.Htmlencode performance versus Regex.Replace versus String.Replace

Tags: asp.net, regex, string

Which is fastest in an ASP.NET app? Trying to catch all manners of naughty XSS/CSRF and the like.

Server.HtmlEncode before displaying, String.Replace calls (one after another), or a complicated regex followed by a Regex.Replace?

Thanks for any info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use Server.HtmlEncode... it's not just the "speed", but the fact that *that* is what the technology is for. It's likely that you're going to forget something in your .Replace().Replace().Replace (which is also slower).

### A bit of explaination

Keep in mind that "Server.HtmlEncode" will make one streaming pass through your string, whereas .Replace().Replace().Replace() will make multiple passes to do the same thing.

Regarding the Regex - you're going to have the overhead the Regex being parsed and compiled in the first place.

Comment: +1, but I wouldn't reject a regex solution out of hand for performance reasons; Regex objects can be pre-instantiated and reused, even compiled to MSIL bytecode and stored permanently in a DLL. What I *would* reject it for is the fact that there's a purpose-made tool readily available--one that *you* don't have to maintain.  Why would anyone even think about using regexes instead?

Answer (score 4):

I'd argue that you will likely never recover the amount of time needed to post this question.  Server.HtmlEncode does the job, does it right, and is "fast enough".  Are you actually seeing performance issues with it?